# Finding similarity between two graphs

Tags: r, igraph

I have two graphs (g1) and (g2), the number of nodes and degree are different in both graphics. I would like to calculate "in some way" how similar are both graphs.
I thought in using something like a Jaccard index, the approach would be something like this:

```
g1 <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 0.3)
g2 <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 0.3) 
g.union <- graph.union(g1, g2)
g.intersect <- graph.intersection(g1, g2, keep.all.vertices=F)

sim.index <- ecount(g.intersect)/ecount(g.union)
```

But I don't know if this make any sense,

Thanks in advance

Comment: `graph.union` and `graph.intersection` use the vertex labels, so if you relabeled the vertices (but didn't change the structure of the graphs) you would get a different answer. If you want a similarity measure that relies on structure instead of vertex labels, you might try the graph edit distance, which has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399597/edit-distance-between-two-graphs). Unfortunately computing it is NP-hard, and it doesn't look like there's an implementation in igraph.

Comment: Chapter 6 of Practical Graph Mining with R (Samatova, et al) explains Neuman Kernels and how to calculate the "relatedness" of two network graphs.  The example on 153-156 uses the packages igraph and ProximityMeasure.

Comment: Thanks @lawyeR, what I cannot find is the package ProximityMeasure, I think the library GraphClusterAnalysis can do something similar but I cannot find it as well

Comment: Here is the Chapter I was referring to -- http://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/samatova/practical-graph-mining-with-R/sample/chapter_6_Proximity.pdf

Comment: did you check this? https://rdrr.io/bioc/BiRewire/man/birewire.similarity.html