# How to find edit distance between two s-expressions?

Tags: compression, scheme, racket, edit-distance

Would such an edit distance be a good measure of expression similarity? What if we wanted a semantic difference of two s-expressions? Can such an edit distance be used for s-expression compression?

Comment: This is a good question, but I think this might be the wrong forum. I'm sad because I'm interested in the answer.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but it doesn't fit the expected format for this site. Please take another look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to make sure your questions can be answered in Stack Overflow. Most of the time, we expect code to be present in the post; open-ended questions are discouraged, as well as questions about programming errors that cannot be reproduced locally by copy-pasting the code in the post.

Comment: To put it another way: please provide the code you've written so far for finding the edit distance between two s-expressions, pointing the parts that are giving you trouble. Also provide sample input and expected output, so anyone can reproduce the problem.

Comment: would cs.stackexchange.com
be a better place? the problem with that site seems to be a lot less users so a lot smaller chance of getting an answer.

Comment: this question has no code included and yet seems to do quite well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399597/edit-distance-between-two-graphs?rq=1

Comment: @X10D you are right that SO is arbitrary in what fits it's rules and what doesn't. Its like a programming language defined by its implementation.  The cs.stackexchange.com might be worth a try

Comment: or any common lisp community.

Comment: please help me brainstorm on this :)
even if you only have a partial idea :)

Comment: Which distance do you have in mind? [The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) lists 5 different.

Comment: is the edit distance with the most edit operations the most universal?